# Obtain the last "n" values from my model from all my devices

Tags: django, django-views

I want to obtain the last values of my different devices from my data model (django). If I want the last one I'm using,

```
dev_data = DevData.objects.order_by('dev_id','-data_timestamp').distinct('dev_id')
```

But I don't know how to obtain the last "n" values of each one (not just the last one). I tried the next code line, but it is wrong because this defines how many values you obtain in total, not for every device.

```
dev_data = DevData.objects.order_by('dev_id','-data_timestamp').distinct('dev_id')[:n]
```

Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which database are you using? You probably need to use a window function

Comment: What is the error your are getting?

Comment: I edited the question. I need for example the last 3 datas of each device.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problems with distinct and order_by? Well, in that case you should use subquery

```
from django.db.models import Subquery

DevData.objects.filter(
    id__in=Subquery(
        DevData.objects.distinct(
            'dev_id'
        ).order_by(
            'dev_id'
        ).values(
            'id'
        )
    )
).order_by(
    '-data_timestamp'
)[:n]
```